# #include "path\\file.h" unable to open file dfm

Tags: c++builder

I changed `#include "Konta.h"` with the given parent folder only:

`#include "Pliki Poczta/Konta.h"`

I create in folder with project folder to which enter files like: `Konta.h`, `Konta.dfm` and `Konta.cpp`

The program compiles but the linker throws an errors:

> [ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to open file 'KONTA.DFM'

How do I indicate where the `Konta.dfm` file is?

Comment: Did you update the search paths in your Project Options?

Comment: Where is this option?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_(Shared_Options)

Comment: Unfortunately but inspite of added paths compilator is searching files in main folder with project

Comment: [bcc32 Fatal Error] Konta.cpp(1): F1009 Unable to open input file 'Konta.cpp'

Comment: try `#include "Pliki Poczta\\Konta.h"` hope the folder `Pliki Poczta` is local to your project if not you need to 1. use absolute address 2. or add its path to include search paths 3. or change the files location to local  ... In case the folder is local but one level up in the folder tree you can use `"\\..\\Pliki Poczta\\Konta.h"` if more then one just add more `\\..\\ ` parts ...

Comment: I deleted all files and compiled again. Now compiler can't open KONTA. OBJ

Comment: 1. you used `#include "???"` that is why compiler uses local path if you want use include paths instead use `#include <???>` 2 What is the architecture of your app code? the KONTA is a VCL Form? Is I it native Form to your App (is it created in project source file and or part of project (AddToProject)?) or is it just included and created dynamicaly. What is the folder structure of your source files ... How and where you include ... for dynamic forms is the `KONTA.cpp` included somewhere too (for example in `KONTA.h`) ? what exactly you deleted (`*.obj,*.map,*.tds`)?